# Using Browserify and RequireJS on the same page?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd, browserify

So i've come across an interesting use case where i'm using Browserify to bundle all of my assets together in a project, but a large external (external to the project) module needs to be loaded in when a certain in-app window is accessed. (It's a video player module made up of three scripts that get pulled in asynchronously when required).

At the moment i'm getting  all kinds of errors from `uncalled object` errors if the requireJS module is loaded in before the Browserified `app.js` file, to `cannot find module` errors if loaded in *after* the Browserified code.

Is there anyway i can get Browserify and RequireJS to play nicely on the same page? I'm losing my mind!

Comment: Try wrapping your bundled javascript in a closure.

Comment: I think it's Browserify adding a require global at the beginning of the bundled file. How would i wrap the entire imported app.js file in a closure without modifying the browserified file?

Comment: Did you ever work around this?  I'm coming from the opposite direction ... most of my app is requirejs, but I want to pull in a single library available on NPM that I plan to package with a browserify wrapper.  So far no luck.

Comment: This might be a death sentence for my use case: "Finally, RequireJS in Node can only load modules that are on the local disk -- fetching modules across http, for instance, is not supported at this time."  <http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html>

Comment: Are any of your modules loaded in the Browserify bundle UMD modules? This could cause an issue if RequireJS is loaded on the page because it might not export to CommonJS if it detects AMD.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR - use `window.require` in your browserified script.

Maybe it would still help someone.
I happen to use an 'external' dojo-based library totally based on requireJS-style AMD, which is absolutely un-"browserifyeble" and un-convertable to CommonJS or anything sane. My own code is totally Browserified. It's working OK like this:

1. Load the AMD loader (which defines the global `require` function) before the browserified script:

   ```
   <script src="dojo/dojo.js"></script> <!-- RequireJS/AMD loader, defining a global 'require'-->
   <script src="app/main.js"></script> <!-- The Browserify bundle -->
   ```
2. In your own js, call the `require` function on `window` object ('cause you'll have a local browserify-`require` shadowing the global one)

   ```
   window.require(['dojo/dojo'], function (dojo) { ... });
   ```
3. The 'external' app or library, which calls `require` on its own to load submodules etc., works just fine 'cause that code is out of browserify context and the global `require` is not shadowed there.

Maybe if you have some pure nice standard RequireJS modules, you could somehow convert them to be Browserifiable, but in my case that wasn't an option.

Comment: great stuff. this helped me a lot

Comment: Very usefull for splitting a large app in module bundles and lazyload them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is a tool called [browserify-derequire](https://github.com/rse/browserify-derequire) that resolves this issue by renaming browserify's require statmenets to avoid the naming collision.

It can be installed with npm using:

```
npm install -g browserify-derequire
```

Use it as a browserify plugin by changin your build command to:

```
browserify src/*.js -p browserify-derequire > module.js
```

There is more discussion on this issue at: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/790

Answer (score 3):

For a gulp friendly solution (similar to what @Cride5 proposed) you can use [gulp-derequire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-derequire) plugin.

Basic example from docs:

```
var derequire = require('gulp-derequire');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('build', function() {
    var bundleStream = browserify({entries: './index.js', standalone: 'yourModule'}).bundle();
    return bundleStream
        .pipe(source('yourModule.js'))
        .pipe(derequire())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./build'));
});
```

Plugin is also based on [derequire](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/derequire) module so all options are supported.